# Updating parent view in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

The goal: Use Backbone to generate a table of users, be able to edit those users inline, and on save, re-render the row with the updated data.

- I'm generating a container table for users with a main UsersView.
- I'm then looping through a users collection, and using a UserView to generate one table row per user.
- Clicking edit on any row needs to replace the row with an edit form. (There are more fields associated with a user than are displayed in the table.)
- Clicking Save should replace the edit form with the updated table row.

Everything works except the re-render of the table row. (If I reload the page, the updated user data is displayed correctly, so I know it's saving.) What I'm trying to do (I think) is get the parent view (UsersView) to listen to the change and re-render the UserView. After dozens of searches and different attempts, I'm here asking for help as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

**// Main users view**

```
var UsersView = Backbone.View.extend( {
  el: '#content',

  template: _.template( usersTemplate ),

  initialize: function( ) {
    var that = this;
    this.listenTo( Users, 'change', this.updateOne );
    Users.fetch( );
    that.render( );
  },

  render: function( ) {
    this.$el.html( this.template );
  },

  // Add a single user to the table
  addOne: function( user ) {
    var userView = new UserView( { model: user } );
    userView.render( ).el;
  },

  // Add all items in the Users collection
  addAll: function( ) {
    Users.each( this.addOne, this );
  }
});
```

**// Individual user view**

```
var UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#usersTableBody',

  tagName:  'tr',

  attributes : function( ) {
    return {
      'data-user' : this.model.get( 'display_name' )
    };
  },

  template: _.template( userTemplate ),

  events: {
    'click .editUser': 'editUser'
  },

  initialize: function( ){ },

  render: function( ) {
    var html = this.template( this.model.attributes );
    this.$el.html( html );
  },

  // Switch user row into edit mode
  editUser: function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault( );

    var userAddEditView = new UserAddEditView( { model: this.model } );
    userAddEditView.render( );
  }
});
```

**// User edit view**

```
var UserAddEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: $( '#content' ),

  template: _.template( userEditTemplate ),

  events: {
    'click .saveUser': 'saveUser'
  },

  initialize: function( options ) { },

  render: function( ) {
    element = '[data-user="' + this.model.get( 'display_name' ) + '"]'
    this.$el.find( element ).hide( ).after( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
  }, 

  saveUser: function( ) {
    var display_name = this.$( '#display_name' ).val( ).trim( );
    var email_address = this.$( '#email_address' ).val( ).trim( );
    var key_email_address = this.$( '#key_email_address' ).val( ).trim( );
    var password = this.$( '#password' ).val( ).trim( );
    var partner_name = this.$( '#partner_name' ).val( ).trim( );
    var hash = this.$( '#hash' ).val( ).trim( );
    var salt = this.$( '#salt' ).val( ).trim( );

    Users.create( { display_name: display_name, key_email_address: key_email_address, email_address: email_address, password: password, partner_name: partner_name, hash: hash, salt: salt } );
  }
});
```

**// User model**

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend( {
  idAttribute: 'key_email_address'
});
```

**// Users collection**

```
var UsersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend( {
  model: User,

  url: 'users',

  initialize : function( models, options ) { },

  parse: function( data ) {
    this.result = data.result;
    return data.users;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `change` event fired when any changes occur on the items of a collection.

So your following line shouldn't really do anything:

`this.listenTo( Users, 'change', this.updateOne );`

you need to include the following in your `UserView` `initialize` method:

`this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.render );`

so now whenever the model is changed (on editing), the current user row is rendered again.

Comment: This wasn't a complete solution, but it got me pointed in the right direction. In addition to the listenTo event on the model, I had to use this.model.save instead of Users.create in the saveUsers function. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: yup ; `create` method is more of a shortcut to new + add in collection. in your case where you are editing an existing model.. you should be using `save`